# org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Failed to find data source: kafka

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

[spark structured streaming kafka in java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4LjhI.png)

This is the part that connects to Spark and receives data through streaming.

```
       <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <filters>
                                <!-- This filter is to workaround the problem caused by included signed jars.
                                     java.lang.SecurityException: Invalid signature file digest for Manifest main attributes
                                -->
                                <filter>
                                    <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                    <excludes>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                    </excludes>
                                </filter>
                            </filters>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer
                                        implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>com.clamos.io.collect.CollectApplication</mainClass>
                                </transformer>
                                <transformer
                                        implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                    <resource>
                                        META-INF/services/org.apache.spark.sql.sources.DataSourceRegister
                                    </resource>
                                </transformer>
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer"/>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

pom.xml

[spark version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GTx3h.png)

spark version  : 3.3.0

java version  : 1.8

**
We are developing logic to receive and check data with spark streaming in kafka. Most people have been advised to use spark-submit. However, I would like it to be applied directly from the source.
How can I do it?**

Comment: You do need to use `spark-submit`, but with your **shaded** JAR, which should have Kafka... You should remove `spark.jars` if you are also trying to download the same with `spark.jars.packages` (these properties are only used if you use `spark-submit`)

Comment: Also, `mvnrepository` is only an index, not a valid Maven repo address

Comment: @OneCricketeer Thanks for commenting...  I don't think I understand Spark properly. Isn't Spark-submit a concept of distributing developed programs to Spark? I want to connect Spark on Java and stream, is this impossible?

Comment: `spark-submit` reads all the necessary Spark classpath libraries and properties to run the code. You can make Intellij run this for you, but using an IDE is not how you'd run Spark in a production environment. You'd create a JAR instead